# mapping in typescript and angular1

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm programming with angular 1.6 and typescript. 
In my project i need to load list of users from the server and display the list with checkboxes near each person:

```
 <div class="container">
  <h2>Hello {{ $ctrl.name }}</h2>
  <ul ng-repeat="user in $ctrl.users"  class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.selected">
      {{user.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$ctrl.showSelected()">save</button>
</div>
```

After user selects some persons and clicks the button below he should get alert with list of selected persons.

Here is Person object that comes from server

```
export class Person {
    public name:string; 
}
```

And my Service looks this way:

```
getUsers() : ng.IHttpPromise<Person[]> {
 return this.$http.get('users.json').then((res:ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<Person[]>)=>{
  return res.data
 })
}
```

Since in my ui the person elements must have "selected" property - i thinking about create uiPerson class which will derive from Person:

```
import { UsersService } from './service'
import { Person } from './Person'
  class uiPerson extends Person{
  public selected:false;
}
export const AppComponent = {
  template: `
  <div class="container">
  <h2>Hello {{ $ctrl.name }}</h2>
  <ul ng-repeat="user in $ctrl.users"  class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.selected">
      {{user.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-    click="$ctrl.showSelected()">save</button>
</div>
`,
 controller: class AppComponent {
 static $inject =["usersService"]
 constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {  }

 $onInit() {
   this.name ='Users';
   this.usersService.getUsers().then(users=>{
     this.users= users as uiPerson[];//<-- HERE IS QUESTION
   }) 
  }
   showSelected() {
     alert(this.users.filter(u=>u.selected).map(u=>u.name).join(','))
   }
}
 };
```

I'm new with typescript - am i right about mapping with "this.users= users as uiPerson[]" syntax? Is there some more correct way to do it?

here is the [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fs7Ye6bdwARjuwdhErfd?p=preview)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks reasonable to me. I would personally make a couple adjustments:

- Make Person and UiPerson interfaces instead of classes, unless you plan to use them in different ways in the future (such as constructing them with `new`)
- Consider whether it makes sense for `selected` to be optional, since at first your array of UiPerson objects will not have it defined. That may also allow you to skip the type cast.

Here is [a revised plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/IsoeJrxQ8EXFsAxr1thT?p=preview) with those changes, and I also took the liberty to make it closer to my personal style, in case you like what you see.

Comment: Excellent advice here.

Comment: Hi, can you please paste some code which shows the differences?

Answer (score 1):

My advice here would be to avoid introducing the uiPerson class - it is adding complexity and polluting your domain model. Is 'selected' truly an attribute of a Person?

What would happen if you were required to present the same Person is two lists?

```
public selectedList1: boolean;
public selectedList2: boolean;
```

Instead - I would look to store the 'selected' state in your Controller, exposing a simple 'isSelected' function:

```
controller: class AppComponent {
    static $inject =["usersService"]
    constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {  }

public selectedUsers: Person[] = [];

$onInit() {
    this.name ='Users';
    this.usersService.getUsers().then(users=>{
        this.users= users; <-- No uiPerson
    }) 
}

showSelected() {
    alert(this.selectedUsers.map(u=>u.name).join(','))
}

isSelected(person: Person): boolean {
    return selectedUsers.indexOf(person) !== -1;
}
```

**Template:**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="$ctrl.isSelected(user)">
```

[Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/vDbFOcsagUKzla5pQz27?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, i had tough time to decide which to mark as "answer", and may be i was wrong